# Hello i'm creating a theme switcher and it functions the first and second time but then it doesen't function, why is it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This is the code that i did, and it functions but the third time that i touch it doesn't change the theme, it's for the image or anything like this?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=> {

    // Theme Switcher
    
    let theme = document.querySelector(".change-them");
    let settingsMenu = document.getElementById("settings-icon");
    let darkColor = "#212121";
    let lightColor = "#fff";
    
    theme.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
        let bg = document.body;
        let h2 = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")
        let h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")
        let h4 = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")
    
    
        // Change Dark Theme to withe theme
    
        if (bg.style.backgroundColor === "" || bg.style.backgroundColor === darkColor) {
            bg.style.backgroundColor = lightColor;
            settingsMenu.style.color = darkColor;
            for (let i = 0; i < h2.length; i++) {
                h2[i].style.color = darkColor;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
                h3[i].style.color = darkColor;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < h4.length; i++) {
                h4[i].style.color = darkColor;
            }
        }
    
    
        // Change white theme to dark theme
    
        else {
            bg.style.backgroundColor = darkColor;
            settingsMenu.style.color = lightColor
            for (let i = 0; i < h2.length; i++) {
                h2[i].style.color = lightColor;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
                h3[i].style.color = lightColor;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < h4.length; i++) {
                h4[i].style.color = lightColor;
            }
        }
    })

})
```

```html
 <div class="settigs-container">
    <div class="change-them">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code html and javascript
I think that i could be because is not in a bucle or maybe i didn't put a property or i selected bad a document, i really don't know why is it, ad I'm learning javascript, so if you can be more specific and teach me something, you will be the best.

I can not public the question because the page says that i must add more details, so i will add more text, this doesn't matter, it's my first time publishing a question so perhaps it doesn't ,ake sense or things like this, but i know that i will improve whit the time so nice

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that it should not be that hard to debug the problem with your browser's developer tools

Comment: What is the value of `bg.style.backgroundColor` the third time the button is pressed?

Comment: I've converted your code into a runnable code snippet and used a placeholder image so we can see something.  It has an error since there is no `#settings-icon` element, but otherwise I think the code works. If you can add that element into your code example that will help